# Transparent logo causing problems on white background

Tags: graphics, graphical-logo

I have a transparent logo that goes through three different colored backgrounds.  It looks good on black and brown, but looks horrible on white.  I'm not sure how I can fix this?

Logo is here

https://i.stack.imgur.com/irypN.png

This is the website where the logo appears

https://seek.estate

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no Photoshop wizzz, but does it look any better? haha

To answer your question about the code, please see this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/C4cBX/).

IT is a transparent background (Like you said) So the background will change depending on what you set in the HTML style & CSS.

For example:

```
<div style="background: #000000; width: 115px;">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/xBTlGq4.png" />
</div>
<div style="background: #FFFFFF; width: 115px;">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/xBTlGq4.png" />
</div>
<div style="background: #000000; width: 115px;">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/xBTlGq4.png" />
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but is there some code I can put so that the background of the <img> tag is black when the blackground of the html is black?

Comment: @user3664594 - I have edited my answer, hopefully that helps you :)